# wordpress custom loop ascending descending posts by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing wordpress site that is depend upon price so i add custom filed named 'price'

```
<?php 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
echo  $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', TRUE);
endwhile;
 ?>
```

it is basic loop to show out price of all post.
**requirement :**
can anybody modify above so its shows post according ascending or descending order like every price site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if I did well, but that's what you need?

```
 <?php query_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>20,'meta_key' => 'price','orderby' => 'meta_value_num','order' => 'ASC',))?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

 echo  $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', TRUE);

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Good Luck